# Как задать размер окна консольного приложения C++ в Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, консоль

Здравствуйте. Захотел написать консольную игрушку на С++. Первым делом решил установить размеры окна консоли. Google сразу пришел на помощь, но проблема в том что все рецепты используют библиотеку windows.h, а на моей машине стоит Ubuntu 16.04. Буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: Концептуально это не верное решение - ваша программа может запросить текущие размеры, но не устанавливать.

Comment: [printf '\e[8;50;100t'](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) из sh установит размер `xterm` в 50x100 символов (для "стандартного" в Ubuntu `gnome-terminal` и `fce4-terminal` тоже работает).

Comment: Вообще, размер самого окна тоже можно установить. Например, это делает утилита wmctrl. Можете использовать ее, или посмотреть как она это делает в исходниках.

Comment: Если приложение консольное, консолью может быть и удаленное подключение и принтер и ещё много чего, что не может поменять свой размер. Поэтому правильным решением будет написание оконного/GUI приложения.

Answer (score 4):

Редкая задачка.

К счастью, еще разработчики [xterm](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm), наряду с реализацией огромного количества [управляющих последовательностей](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) (Control Sequences) типичных для распространенных текстовых терминалов (управление курсором, цветом, набором символов, вставкой, удалением и сдвигом текста и т.д. и т.п.), подумали об аналогичных последовательностях для перемещения окна эмулятора и изменении его размера на экране оконной системы X-windows ([в приведенной выше ссылке](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) их можно найти поиском по тексту *Window manipulation*).

Для изменения размера окна в символах используется последовательность:

**ESC [ 8; *height*; *width*; t**

Где *ESC* -- это символ с кодом 033 (восьмеричный) 27 (десятичный) или "\e" в строке.

Вообще, в [том же документе](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) для последовательность символов `ESC` `[`  используется термин *CSI* (Control Sequince Introducer)
 (другие часто встречающиеся в управлении терминалом последовательности -- *DCS* `ESC` `P` (Device Control String), *OSC* `ESC` `]` (Operating System Command) и *ST* `ESC` `\` (String Terminator)).

Маленькая демо программа на C/C++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define COLS 24
#define ROWS 80

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int cols = av[1] ? atoi(av[1]) : COLS,
    rows = av[1] && av[2] ? atoi(av[2]) : ROWS;
  if (cols < 0)
    cols = COLS;
  if (rows < 0)
    rows = ROWS;

  printf("\e[8;%d;%d;t", cols, rows); 

  return fflush(stdout) == EOF;
}
```

Хотя в документе написано, что если *width* или *height* (ширина и высота (количество строк)) опущены, то используется их текущее значение, а если равны нулю, то берутся некоторые значения по умолчанию (display's height or width), но в моих экспериментах с 
 bash-скриптом `resize.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "\e[8;$1;$2;t"
```

в обеих случаях окно менялось на стандартный размер 24 х 80 символов.

В Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS изменение размера окна работает по крайней мере в терминалах `gnome-terminal` и `xfce4-terminal` (а вот в `xterm` версии `XTerm(322)` ничего не меняется(!!!)).