# Как устанавливать размер терминала ncurses

Tags: c++, linux, ncurses

Возможно ли на ncurses установить размер терминала, в котором выполняется программа?

Comment: #include <curses.h>

int resizeterm(int lines, int columns);

Этот метод не помогает ?

Comment: @vegorov что-то вообще ничего не меняет:

Comment: `#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
       initscr();
       resizeterm(50,140);
       getch();
       endwin();
} `

Comment: Ладно, я не нашел, как это сделать с ncurses, но нашел это:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/602412/288727