# Как запустить консольную программу в полный экран на C/C++?

Tags: c++, linux, c, консоль

При запуске консольной программы терминал открывается не на весь экран. Как сделать так что б он открывался на весь, на чистом C/C++, без WinAPI (на Linux)? Какой функцией можно так сделать?

Comment: вы путаете ide с языком

Comment: т.е. запуск проги зависит только от ide в которой работаешь?

Comment: если для вас запуск проги - это тыкнуть в определенные кнопку в вашей ide - то да

Comment: Если терминал не позволяет себя контролировать (а он скорее всего не позволяет себя контролировать), то скорее всего никак. А позволяет или нет — это уже обращайтесь к документации используемого вами терминала. Каких-то общих для всех функций вроде бы нет

Comment: если я например запускаю прогу из файлового менеджера, то она автоматически откроется, но не в полноэкранном режиме, следовательно, нужно передать какие то параметры в компилятор, для открытия. вот и вопрос есть ли такие на gcc/g++

Comment: Нет таких. . . .

Comment: Когда Вы запускаете консольную программу, она не запускает терминал. Его для неё запускает IDE (если запуск из под IDE) или операционная система, если запуск из файлового менеджера.

Comment: @RichardTry Ок, тогда по логике, такой "запуск" терминала не получится изменить, а только довольствоваться тем что есть

Comment: Возможно, ответ содержится здесь:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/602042/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-c-%D0%B2-linux

Comment: @Sergey спасибо, понял, принял, обработал, работает. Как я только этот пост сразу не нашел

Comment: раз уж нашли дубликат - надо закрыть как дубликат, чтоб новые искатели видели плашку сверху